# Installing Linux on a Windows Dell XPS 13

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, dell-xps

I can buy from a retailer with employee discount. This means that I can get a Dell XPS 13 with Windows for considerably less money than the Dell XPS 13 developer edition from Dell directly. I would like to know whether I can install an Ubuntu on that laptop, or whether this would be a problem (i.e. I would like to know if Dell ships a modified ubuntu or the one from ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same laptop, to run linux on it, but it's not that great...

[Linux support for Dell XPS 13 9343](https://major.io/2015/02/03/linux-support-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-model/)

Fortunately, if you're looking to run Ubuntu on it, this month, Dell announced a developer edition running (modified?) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[XPS 13 Developer Edition](http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd)